# Google Play Game Services: invite player dialog lacks search by name

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm using the stock "select players" dialog provided by the Google Play Game Services API (GamesClient.getSelectPlayersIntent).

The dialog is great but it lacks a very important feature: I cannot search for a friend / opponent by name and therefore I have to stare at that endless list of people who are in my circles.

Maybe I'm missing the obvious, but I cannot find any search feature. No menu item, no text input field... Is there some undocumented intent extras parameter for enabling that feature? Or do I have to create my own dialog with search feature?

Is there an alternative dialog that allows that kind of search?

Answer (score 1):

If you look here [GGS demo page](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/multiplayer#connecting_players) you will see

> You can use the built-in player picker UI provided by game services or implement your own custom UI. To launch the built-in player picker UI, use the Intent returned by GamesClient.getSelectPlayersIntent():

In looking at the GamesClient documentation here [Google GamesClient documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html), you need to utilize the

> public void loadInvitablePlayers (OnPlayersLoadedListener listener, int pageSize, 
>   boolean forceReload)
>
> Load the initial page of players the currently signed-in player can
>   invite to a multiplayer game, sorted alphabetically by name.
>
> The result is delivered to the given listener on the main thread. If
>   disconnect() is called before the result is ready it will not be
>   delivered. Parameters listener    the listener that is called when the
>   load is complete. The listener is called on the main thread. pageSize
>     the number of entries to request for this initial page. Note that if
>   cached data already exists, the returned buffer may contain more than
>   this size, but it is guaranteed to contain at least this many if the
>   collection contains enough records. This must be a value between 1 and
>   25. forceReload   If true, this call will clear any locally cached data and attempt to fetch the latest data from the server. This would
>   commonly be used for something like a user-initiated refresh.
>   Normally, this should be set to false to gain advantages of data
>   caching.

and then decide how you want your UI to work with the returned PlayerBuffer object in the listener.

Comment: I guess Google needs to put some more work into this. The optimal solution would be to provide a name / circle filter with that method call :-( Anyway, I got used to testing with that really long list of people I don't know. Google+ works in mysterious ways

Comment: True, I guess they just want to remind us how many people we track with Google+, as potential invitees to the app.